# Wordpress Issue: JavaScript must be enabled to use this feature. Possibly PHP related?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm having a host of strange problems with Wordpress. I've scoured the internet for other people who may have had this problem, but as far as I can tell I'm the only.

Basically, I'm seeing at a couple locations on a website I'm designing this message: "JavaScript must be enabled to use this feature." However, Javascript *is* enabled. I've checked on multiple browsers and multiple computers and I'm getting the same message.

There are other strange things going on as well, that I strongly suspect are related:

1. When logging into the admin area, I get a message that says "ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress." However, cookies are enabled, and when I click the login button again, it works correctly.
2. In the Themes area, there is no "add new" button at the top.
3. When you hover over the Wordpress left hand menu, the sub-menu items don't show up until you click.

I've tried for hours every solution I could find:

1. Increasing the memory limits
2. Checking permissions of the folders and files
3. Re-Installing Wordpress with a fresh database
4. Checking the PHP version (7.X)
5. Checking the WP Debug thing for errors (none)
6. Deactivating all plugins and themes

We've set everything up on a server running Windows Server 2016, including installing Apache, PHP My Admin, etc... all ourselves. I'm FAR from a server guru, and I'm sure we've messed something up with that.

So my question is: does anybody have any thoughts on what might be causing these issues?

Thank you,

Justin

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I have tried in several browsers and on different computers - same problems.

Comment: See: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/166181/cant-log-in-error-cookies-are-blocked-or-not-supported-by-your-browser-you

Comment: I've never had that issue, and I have multiple WordPress websites. That said, WordPress blows, and is possibly the worst example of code development ever. I'm not surprised you're having problems. Anyway, what web browser are you using? Have you tried a different browser? Have you tried looking in your browser's console to find any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Hey Brian, do you know how to go about looking for JavaScript errors?